# Is it possible to purge dark side energies from a person?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-force, sith

In both canon and Legends, Force users who channelled their dark side energies into a kyber crystal form the basis for such corrupted crystals and the subsequent blades acquiring their signature crimson colouration.

There are also precedents of skilled Jedi purging such crystals of the dark side infused within them, thus purifying these crystals and, metaphorically speaking, bringing them back into the light. For example, in Legends it is rumoured that rare yellow-bladed lightsabers such as that wielded by Temple Guards use such purified crystals. In canon, we know that Ahsoka's Imperial-era white-bladed lightsabers were the result of purifying kyber crystals looted from a slain Inquisitor.

Is it possible to apply the same principle on Force users? I guess dark side users most probably cannot be "exorcised" and brought back to the light by force (no pun intended). However, can other effects be achieved? For example, a dark side user may possibly be severed, however momentarily, from his dark side powers when he has no dark side energies to draw upon, however momentarily. This is just an example from my own imagination off the top of my head.

Are there any recorded incidents, be it in canon or Legends, that suggest such purging procedures to be possible? If yes, what kind of effects can be yielded?

Comment: What, like removing all the [thetans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thetan) from them?

Answer (score 5):

## No.

**probably...**

Khyber crystals are a strange "living" crystal which focuses and amplifies the Force.  They are like capacitors or batteries;  they themselves cannot be "corrupted" by the force;  they do not have a preferred alignment.  They just accept, focus, and amplify the living Force.

Living beings, however, can be twisted and recongifured by the Force which flows through the user.  Constant use of the dark side twists the user toward dark;  heavy use of the light side likewise makes one more intune to the light side of the force.

Unlike khyber crystals, you can't simply "drain" the force alignment of a living creature and "refill" it with a different alignment of the force.  You can convince a force user to switch sides, which requires them to change their own use of the force to tune themselves.  But it's not the same process.

Answer (score 3):

The closest I could find is a legends light-side power called [Sever Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sever_Force). While not exactly "bringing people back into the light", it was used in a sense to purge dark side powers from a person by removing their connection to the force altogether.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you ask:

> For example, **a dark side user may possibly be severed, however momentarily, from his dark side powers when he has no dark side energies to draw upon**, however momentarily. This is just an example from my own imagination off the top of my head.

In the sense that the dark side can be purged from a person, no, I couldn't find any evidence of that, as Zoey Boles discusses above, but in answer to the example that you give at the bottom of your question, yes it is possible to do that.

Mwr247 mentions the general Force ability of [Sever Force](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sever_Force) which can be used either by light side or dark side users of the Force and can be permanent or temporary. When it is used by a single light side user of the Force it is called [Force Light](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_Light), quoted from the Wookieepedia article:

> **Force light would weaken the darksider's connection to the Force. With the light of the Force, a Jedi could either purge or contain dark side manifestations ... or even living persons**, though sometimes to detrimental effect. By channeling the Force into withering blasts of light-side energy, the darkness can then be diminished or destroyed permanently.

When several Jedi worked together, they could produce an even stronger version of Force Light, called [Wall of Light](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wall_of_light):

> A wall of light was an immense manifestation of potentially destructive light side Force energy created by the focused power of a united Jedi front. **When performed successfully, a wall of light allowed participants to effectively contain or purge the power of the dark side from a specific location, or sever an especially dangerous darksider from their Force connection**.

The Wookieepedia articles have several examples, although all from Legends.